# Testing if a request is anonymous or authenticated WebAPI 2 + Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm using WebAPI 2 + ASP.NET Identity

In one of my ApiController methods, I would like to test if a particular HTTP request is coming from an authenticated client or not (i.e. whether the request contains an authorization header or not).

The following works, but maybe there is a better way?

```
private AuthContext db = new AuthContext();

// GET api/Orders/
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetOrder(int id)
{
    // ApplicationUser is an IdentityUser.
    ApplicationUser currentUser = null;

    try
    {
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
        currentUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.GetUserName());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    if ( currentUser == null )
    {
        // Anonymous request.
        // etc...




    } else {
        // Authorized request.
        // etc...
    }
}
```

I am using the default routing template. Another option would be to route to 2 different methods for authorized requests and anonymous requests (decorated with appropriate data annotations).

Comment: You should be able to use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` -- have you tried this already?

Comment: Thanks, that works! Missed that one. I will mark this correct if you feel like typing up an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `ApiController` class in WebApi there is a `User` property (which you are already making use of in your code: `User.Identity.GetUserName()`).

This `User` property is an `IPrincipal` instance which has a property `Identity` which is an instance of `IIdentity`.

Within the code of an `ApiController` method you can test whether the user for the current request is Authenticated by testing the `IsAuthenticated` property of `User.Identity`.

For example:

```
if ( User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // Authenticated user...do something
}
else
{
   // anonymous..do something different
}
```